# 'int' object not callable?

Tags: python, pygame

I keep getting the error "int object not callable", but even after looking around the internet and stack overflow, i can't deduce the fix. I thought maybe it could've been caused by the pygame.quit function, but i'm not sure whats wrong with mine exactly.

```
# Imports--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

import pygame


# initialization-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

pygame.init()

# Flags----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

gameExit = False

# Variables -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

display_height = 500
display_width = 500

# Colors --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

FUCHSIA = (255, 0, 255)
PURPLE = (128, 0, 128)
TEAL = (0, 128, 128)
LIME = (0, 255, 0)
GREEN = (0, 128, 0)
OLIVE = (128, 128, 0)
YELLOW = (255, 255, 0)
ORANGE = (255, 165, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
MAROON = (128, 0, 0)
SILVER = (192, 192, 192)
GRAY = (128, 128, 128)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
NAVY = (0, 0, 128)
AQUA = (0, 255, 255)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)

# Draw Screen----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

win = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Airbender Training")
Clock = pygame.time.Clock()


# Main Loop------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

while not gameExit:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT():
            Exit = True

    win.fill((0, 0, 0))
    Clock.tick(60)
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Hi, it would help if you post the error message. Thanks. This will tell us which line is causing an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pygame.QUIT` is a numerical constant, not a function. In general, capital variable names means some kind of constant.

If you print out `pygame.QUIT`, you'll get `12`, an integer. Putting the parentheses after it with `pygame.QUIT()` is basically saying `12()`, which obviously makes no sense.

So just change:

```
if event.type == pygame.QUIT():
```

to

```
if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
```

You can check out all the different types of events at http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html

Comment: Thanks! The only issue now is that the closing red X button doesn't work. I don't get an error in the console, but just clicking close doesn't get it to actually exit

Comment: @TyronePope Did you mean `gameExit = True` instead of `Exit = True`?

Comment: That solved the issue, thanks buds, I really appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

The error is in this line:

```
if event.type == pygame.QUIT():
```

`pygame.QUIT` is just a constant (an `int` constant, actually), and is not supposed to be called - you just check if the `event.type` has the same value as it.

```
if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
```

will fix it for you.

Answer (score 1):

In line 50. `pygame.QUIT` is an integer. Remove the `()`

```
while not gameExit:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: # here
            Exit = True
```

Answer (score 0):

if event.type == pygame.QUIT():

QUIT is an integer, you can't invoke it like a function. Remove the parentheses.